# How to map @embeddable entity to view i.e jsp so that I can get embeddable data from the user, like we do for @entity using @modelAttribute.

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

//This the Controller class method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("register") User user) {
    boolean result = false;
    if(user.getId()==0){
        result = userService.addUser(user);
    }else{
         userService.updateUser(user);
    }

    System.out.println("result "+result);
    return "redirect:/signup";
}
```

//Entity with @Embeddable class

@Entity
public class User {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;
private String age;
private String passion;
private String goal;
@Embedded
private Address address;
```

//Here's the @Embeddabel class

@Embeddable
public class Address {

```
private String street;
private String city;
private String country;
private String pincode;
```

// JSP View

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td><form:input path="id" type="hidden" readonly="true"/></td>
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="age">Age</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="age"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td><form:label path="passion">Passion</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="passion"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="goal">Goal</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="goal"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="street">STREET</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="street"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="city">CITY</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="city"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="country">COUNTRY</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="country"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><form:label path="pincode">PICODE</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="pincode"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><c:if test="${!empty register.name }">
        <td><input type="submit" value="Edit User"></td>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty register.name }">
            <td><input type="submit" value="Add User"></td>
        </c:if>
    </tr>
</table>
```

//when I load the page it throws an error as

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Embedded annotation help hibernate, how to  Embedded object deal with Entity class, It does not help to java 
For java pojo, it just an association relation b/w your main class and Address class

So instead to call directly street or any fields of the address you need to call reference of address

eg:

`<td><form:input path="address.street"/></td>`

Comment: np,have a great day :)